# How can i define default binder for type in MVC6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have following working code:

```
public ObjectResult GetDocumentById([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder))] CustomId id)
```

How can I specify `CustomModelBinder` to be the default binder for `CustomId` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried decorating your `CustomId` class with `ModelBinderAttribute`?

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder))]
public class CustomId { }
```

You can also register your model binder directly in `ConfigureServices` in your `Startup` class (note that `IModelBinderProvider` no longer exists in ASP.NET 5):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.ConfigureMvc(options => {
        options.ModelBinders.Insert(0, new CustomModelBinder());
    });
}
```

Since your model binder will be the first one to be invoked, return `null` when it cannot handle the model type to make sure the built-in binders will still be invoked for other types:

```
public class CancellationTokenModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public Task<ModelBindingResult> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(CancellationToken))
        {
            var model = bindingContext.OperationBindingContext.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
            var validationNode =
                new ModelValidationNode(bindingContext.ModelName, bindingContext.ModelMetadata, model);
            return Task.FromResult(new ModelBindingResult(
                model,
                bindingContext.ModelName,
                isModelSet: true,
                validationNode: validationNode));
        }

        return Task.FromResult<ModelBindingResult>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering! I can't decorate type with ModelBinder attribute cause it's from compiled dll. When i just register my binder in options - it's not working.

Comment: Then you should try to insert it at the top of the model binders list to make sure your model is not handled by another greedy binder: `options.ModelBinders.Insert(0, new CustomModelBinder())`

Comment: I tried to do this, but in that case all models are bound by my custom binder, even strings.  @Pinpoint.

Comment: Remember that with MVC 6, you're supposed to return null if your model binder cannot handle the model type: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions/ModelBinding/IModelBinder.cs#L21

Comment: I return NULL from binder and controller method is not called.

Comment: Are you sure that's not caused by another issue or a bug in your binder? If you need a sample, take a look at the built-in binders: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/CancellationTokenModelBinder.cs

Comment: Thank you! It was my mistake,  returned  `null` instead of `Task.FromResult<ModelBindingResult>(null)`. Thank you for help! Can you update answer to mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to have a custom binder that, instead of `null`, binds empty string to the properties of type `string`

```
    public Task<ModelBindingResult> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);

        if ((bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(string)) && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.FirstValue)))
        {
            var result = ModelBindingResult.Success(key, string.Empty);
            return Task.FromResult<ModelBindingResult>(result);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<ModelBindingResult>(default(ModelBindingResult));
    }
```

Note that compared to the answer posted above, in DNX 1.0.0-rc1-update1, the line

```
return Task.FromResult<ModelBindingResult>(null);
```

causes a compile error because `ModelBindingResult` is a struct (a non-nullable value type).
Try changing it to the following in order to fix the compile error

```
return Task.FromResult<ModelBindingResult>(default(ModelBindingResult));
```